# How to fetch hindi text from database in laravel php,

Tags: laravel

when m trying to fetch Hindi text its showing  question marks, how to resolve them, please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPiU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure, that everything from your database to the output you send to the browser is encoded in a charset, that covers Hindi, e.g. UTF-8.

- Make sure the database table and field are using a utf8 charset and collation
- Make sure that it matches the utf8 collation set in your laravel configuration file `config/database.php` -> connections -> mysql/connection name -> charset / collation keys.
- Make sure that the output you send to the browser is set to utf8 charset:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```